# Data analysis on radicle length?

Tags: anova, standard-deviation, biostatistics

I am doing an experiment on the effect of different soaking time on radicle length.

I have five treatments: 6 hr, 12 hr, 18 hr, 24 hr and 30 hr. Each treatment has 5 replicates/repetitions. And each trial/replicate has about 5 seeds in them. Time of soaking-independent variable; length of radicle-dependent variable.

Consider that I have 5 seeds in each trial/replicate. I am measuring the length of the radicle of each seed and it results in 5 radicle lengths in each trial. So for 5 trials, I have about 25 radicle lengths in total. In order to calculate the standard deviation and to perform the ANOVA test, do I need to average the 5 radicle lengths in each trial (do that for the rest of the four trials) and then use the 5 mean radicle lengths?

Opposed to this, what I did was I took the standard deviation of the 25 radicle lengths (combined all trials into one unit) rather than the 5 average radicle lengths (5 trials). The standard deviation of the 25 radical lengths was immensely different from the standard deviation of the 5 average radical lengths.

What do you think is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What is a "trial"? Do you mean that you have five different treatments?

Comment: I do have five treatments: 6 hr, 12 hr, 18 hr, 24 hr and 30 hr. What I meant by 5 trials is that each treatment has 5 replicates/repetitions. And each trial/replicate has about 5 seeds in them.

Comment: How are the trials different? Are you comfortable combining them? // It would be best not to consider the time as a category, since there is a clear order to the times.

Comment: The trials are different in the sense that I grew them in different containers (5 seeds each in 5 containers) under the same conditions.

Comment: I came across a research paper with a similar topic that took the average seedling length of one trial to end up with 5 average seedling length for one treatment. They then used this to calculate the standard deviation.

Comment: "To analyze our data, we performed a set of calculations to first find the means, then the 95% confidence intervals. Firstly, we found the average length of the ten seedlings in each Petri dish. Next, we averaged the mean growths for the three Petri dishes in each treatment where each Petri dish represented one replicate; for this calculation n=3. We then found the variance and standard deviation which we used to calculate the 95% confidence interval for each treatment." But I wasn't sure if this was the right method or not.

Comment: For (all?) the other ones who do not understand *radicle*, see https://www.britannica.com/science/radicle